# Tableau-Build bar chart with reference lines with dynamic data

Tags: charts, visualization, tableau-desktop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1Vir.jpg)

Hello world,

This question is for tableau user.I’m trying to achieve two thing displayed on the image above:

1. Bar chart up to 100%, color coded (negative<50, 50<neutral<70; positive>70)
2. grey horizontal bar lines with the score results: (group 1= 50, group 2=75, group 3=100)

I have been playing around with reference lines but I can’t find a solution, particularly because the score results refresh/change daily

Thanks internet! :)

Comment: Can you please share your existing work in Tableau Public like this : https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/debayan.kar/vizzes